# Compare tables base on Id and generate Insert statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two DB(every thing is same schema, etc...) staging & Prod.

Both has table called "Prod.Product" & "Staging.Product"

I would like to compare these two tables base on id for example Id=1 and generate insert statement

```
select * from Prod.Product  
except
select * from Staging.Product
```

Comment: I am seeing two queries based on your description.  Please add some sample data to make your question clearer.

Comment: if you are inserting on the basis of same tables better use `merge`!!!!

Comment: any tool you can suggest. I have use VS for database compression but not sure how to compare data. Any advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you need to generate insert statement? Just execute it. As far as I understand, you want to insert in `Prod.Product` the rows from `Staging.Product` with ID values that does not exists. You can do it like this:

```
insert into Prod.Product
select * from Staging.Product s
where not exists(select 1 from Prod.Product p where p.Id = s.Id)
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you very much. I would like to know how can I do this with relationship b/w tables such as customer  -> Orders -> Order details  Or

Course -> studentCourse -> Student

Comment: You are welcome, but I don't quite understand your question. What do you mean with "relationship b/w" tables? In this scenario you copy the data table per table, so relations doesn't really matter. Just replace `Product` with the corresponding table name (customer, Orders, etc.) and if needed adjust the name of the key field (Id).

Comment: Hi, thank for response. Actually client have deleted data in production environment 3 tables ( 3 tables have relationship 1 to many, etc) We have backup.   I would like to write a query to restore all tables data. above example will restore product table only. How can I write a query to restore all data (3 tables)

Product -> Orders -> OrdersDetail. 

Note: Because of security I can't disclose tables names. Thanks for help

Comment: To copy the data for each table, you need a separate query for it. Just replace the table name `Product` in the query above, with the name of your secret tables (e.g. `Orders` or `OrdersDetail`). For example `insert into Prod.Orders select * from Staging.Orders s where not exists(select 1 from Prod.Orders p where p.Id = s.Id)` and `insert into Prod.OrdersDetails select * from Staging.OrdersDetails s where not exists(select 1 from Prod.OrdersDetails p where p.Id = s.Id)`. You may need to adjust the schema (`Prod`) and key (`Id`) names too.